# jQuery Pass XML Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing, loops

I have the following jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://f.cl.ly/items/0i1V1L1k2F440L1m2Y0G/pointdata.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('point').each(function() {
        var lat = $(this).children('lat').text();
        var long = $(this).children('long').text();
        alert(lat + long);
    });
}
```

Trying to read data from [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/0i1V1L1k2F440L1m2Y0G/pointdata.xml) XML file

You can also see a live jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/STe25/1/)

For some reason, the variables lat and long aren't being assigned for each element. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
​

Comment: Let me guess. `http://f.cl.ly/` is a third party domain.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work because of the same origin policy restriction which forbids you from sending cross domain AJAX requests. Are you sure that you didn't violate this policy in your actual code? So unless your script is hoisted on `http://f.cl.ly/` you cannot send AJAX requests to it.

Comment: Updated it, by adding it as a resource, but still no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/STe25/2/

Comment: @jacktheripper When in doubt, always add an `error` callback and investigate the Ajax error you get.

Comment: @jacktheripper, no you didn't add it as resource. You just added a reference to it. The file is still located on `f.cl.ly` and your updated jsfiddle doesn't work because you are getting a 404 error. Please use FireBug to see those errors. So as everyone already stated here: you cannot send cross domain AJAX calls.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov. And as my answer shows, this is your ONLY problem, you can't ignore it by "adding a resource" to jsfiddle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `parseXML` function [works](http://jsfiddle.net/eK7Kt/)

You're probably violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
You can't send `ajax` requests to other domains.

Note that `lat + long` concats **strings** so `'1' + '2'` is `'12'` **not 3**.
If you want the result to be 3, parse to int first.